# Regex match strings not in certain brackets

Tags: regex

does anyone know how to code a regex to get all the `123`s that are NOT in the `apple` and `banana` brackets in the following text?

```
apple = {
      123 1647 4939 5025 
}
grape = {
      1647 123 1647 4939 5025 
}
grape_number = 123
123 = {
      orang_number = 456
}
banana = {
       1647 123 1647 4939 5025 
}
```

Comment: Are you using any programming language here, and, if so, which one?

Comment: well it is a independently developed language that I'm testing, it counts as a custom C I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regex flavour allows non-fixed-width negative lookbehinds, you can use this regex:

```
(?<!(?:apple|banana) *= *{[^{}]*)123
```

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/k9EjIx/1).

---

Otherwise, you can use some heuristics like for the expression below (working in PCRE):

```
(?<!apple)(?<!banana)(?<=\w) *= *{[^{}]*\K123|123(?![^{}]*\})
```

This matches every `123` that is not wrapped within curly brackets or, if it is, the brackets are not "assigned" to `apple` or to `banana`.

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/MD3orz/1).

---

If neither the `\K` operator is allowed, you can use this:

```
(?<!apple)(?<!banana)(?<=\w) *= *{[^{}]*(123)|(123)(?![^{}]*\})
```

and extract groups `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: just an extra question, do you have a solution if non-fixed-width negative lookbehinds isn't allowed?

Comment: In languages that support callback functions, you could use them here to avoid lookbehinds.

Comment: @Jim I added another possible solution.